# IntelliJ not showing hadoop errors

Tags: java, debugging, hadoop, intellij-idea

I set all the environment to run `hadoop` applications in `IntelliJ`. Now, I experienced some issue because my code was compiling with no error message, despite the fact that I had no `hadoop` output.

So, I had to build the artifact, run it on my local `hadoop`, and then getting this error

```
Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext, but class was expected
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
```

I was then able to debug it. My question is why this error did not show in my `IntelliJ` console ?

Edit : in the screenshot, the `run configuration` settings.

[image]

and my local command

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:57826,suspend=y,server=n -Dvisualvm.id=1437944439130793000 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-doclet.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/htmlconverter.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Users/$myusername/Desktop/Sites/hadoop/avrosation/out/production/avrosation:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.7.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.7.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.7.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-api-2.7.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-2.7.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-client-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-framework-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-recipes-2.7.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/gson-2.2.4.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.7.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-2.7.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpclient-4.2.5.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpcore-4.2.5.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/jets3t-0.9.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.0/libexec/share/hadoop/common/lib/snappy-java-1.0.5.jar:/Users/$myusername/Documents/artifacts/avro-1.7.7.jar:/Users/$myusername$myusername/Documents/artifacts/avro-mapred-1.7.7-hadoop2.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 13 CE.app/lib/idea_rt.jar" org.avrosation.ParseXML /Users/$myusernameyusername/Desktop/Sites/hadoop/avrosation/outfile.avro outfiles
```

Comment: Interesting observation. Would you provide IntelliJ's "Run configuration" and your local hadoop command parameters?

Comment: @gonbe I have just made an edit. Is that the informations you're looking for ?

Comment: Good. You added the IntelliJ setting and its run command. Would you provide your "local hadoop" command, that gave the exception message, as well?

Comment: @gonbe : my hadoop command was simply `hadoop jar myartifact.jar input.avro output`

Comment: I found difference in program arguments. Can you try updating IntelliJ run configuration using the same arguments as hadoop command?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Any luck on finding a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your IntelliJ doesn't behave the same as `hadoop` command is because the main class is different.

Your IntelliJ's "run configuration" shows ParseXML as main class for JVM, while `hadoop` command runs [RunJar](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/util/RunJar.java) as main class, which would take your ParseXML class and its arguments as program arguments

In addition to main class, you can check [hadoop command](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/bin/hadoop) (it's just a shell script; `sh -x` helps) to see what it's doing for environmental variable and system property before invoking the main class for `java` command.

Comment: thanks for your response but in facture I used to have some code that I rand the same way and that showed me correctly the `hadoop` errors in the `intellij` console

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to compare the old class and the ParseXML class (Both run in IntelliJ). Would you share them?